# how to show the data in list using cursor in android

Tags: android

I am getting the from the database using cursor but when i am trying to show the data in list, it is not showing..

the below code is for accessing the data using cursor from database:

```
protected void showCustomerdetails() {

    try
    {
        Cursor cursor = m_dbManager.getValues("customer", new String[]{"name","mobile_phone" }, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int i = 0;
            while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
                m_uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                Log.d("debug","getting the name from cursor");
                m_mobnum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile_phone"));
                cursor.moveToNext();
                i++;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

now the below code is for adding the data in the list---

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{   
 Activity context;   
 IconicAdapter(Activity context) 
 {   
     super(context, R.layout.custoemrs_list);   
     this.context=context;   
 }   

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {  
    View row = null;
    try
    {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();   
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custoemrs_list, null);
            TextView des=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.custusername);   
            des.setText(m_uname);

            TextView qty=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.custmobnum);
            qty.setText(m_mobnum);



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return row;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the Cursor and setting the same variable over and over with a different value, until it finally reaches the end of the cursor.

Instead, you need to read it once per call in the getView() method.

look into this part:

```
while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
{
 m_uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")); // <-- BAD!
 Log.d("debug","getting the name from cursor");
 m_mobnum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile_phone")); // <-- BAD!
 cursor.moveToNext();
 i++; // <-- UNUSED!
}
```

You are not using `i` for anything here. Rather, you are replacing the values of `m_uname` and `m_mobnum` constantly. A simple way to make it to work is to create a couple of ArrayList and do

```
ArrayList<String> m_uname = new ArrayList<String>();
//

while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
{
 m_uname.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
 Log.d("debug","getting the name from cursor");
 m_mobnum.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile_phone")));
 cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

You would then use it as

```
des.setText(m_uname.get(position));
```

Comment: IconicAdapter(Activity context) 
 {   
     super(context, R.layout.custoemrs_list,m_uname);   
     this.context=context;   
 }   I change the above code like this.